# How to write CMakeLists.txt or Makefile to avoid conflicts when there're multiple implementations share the same interface in C?

Tags: c, makefile, cmake

I have a C project with directory like this:

```
./I.h
./config.h
./one/{I.h, I.c}
./two/{I.h, I.c}
```

The interfaces are defined in I.h, two different implementations are in two folders *one* and *two*, we could define some macros in config to select which implementation I want. So, in I.h, it looks like:

```
#if   defined(USE_ONE)
  #include "./one/I.h"
#elif defined(USE_TWO)
  #include "./two/I.h"
#else
  #error ...
#endif
```

I wonder how could I write the Makefile or CMakeLists.txt that could avoid compile the projects without conflicts.

Thanks!

Comment: If you have a C project, why are you tagging with C++? :)

Comment: @tonysdg Because the answer will apply to both C and C++ (and any other language CMake supports)?

Comment: @immibis Fair point, I only ask because the entire question is geared toward C (including the title).

Comment: If you have the same interface, why would you have two header files? Just link the configured _implementation_ and use a single, **common** header for the interface.

Comment: Use the `add_definitions()` cmake macro? I am sorry I don't understand the problem, what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @Olaf yes, using a common header file is way to go. but this approach will be cleaner and easy to customize. for example, if I want to add another implementation *three*, what I need to do is to add very less codes in the header file. and it will be more flexible, you could have some specific interfaces in three/I.h. currently, I know I could write a python script to achieve it.

Comment: It actually is the obbosite of "cleaner" and "easy to customise". If a user of the header relies on specific extras, it will also be dependent on the specific implementation. The accepted method is to use a common header for the **common** interface and additional **specific** headers for the **specific** interfaces of a specific implementation. That way you do not have to modify the common interface header if you add specific interfaces or even add a forth or fifth or hundredth implementation.

Comment: And Python is a programming language, not a scripting language. Btw: If you already use Python, why don't you use a Python-based build-system like SCons? One language for all - with full Python-access to build information.

Comment: @Olaf I thought about your idea of using the common interfaces and specific interfaces approach, it's a good idea. but is providing extra header files for specific interfaces makes the structure more complicated ? I have tried using SCons in my previous project, and it's very convenient, but get complicated when the project grows. Probably I did not use it in the right way...will try it later when there's a suitable project.

Comment: @blackball: More than `#ifdef` possibly spread all over the header and editing every time one of the specific interfaces changes or is added? - Don't think so. Perhaps you can even bundle some of the specific interfaces to anoter single header, much like in higher level languages you can bundle the OOP-interfaces.

Comment: @Olaf Good point. But if I use a common header file, the original problem still remains, we still need conditional compilation to make it work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96693/discussion-between-olaf-and-blackball).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own variable and then set the value for it when invoking `cmake`.

Define the variable in `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
SET(IMPL "one" CACHE STRING "Choose I implementation") # 'one' is default value
```

Then check value:

```
IF ("${IMPL}" EQUAL "one")
    # Set sources including files in folder one
ELSEIF ("${IMPL}" EQUAL "two")
    # Set sources including files in folder two
ENDIF ("${IMPL}" EQUAL "one")
```

Then you can run `cmake -DIMPL:STRING=<one|two>`

Comment: If I did this, then there's no need to have a config.h file in the project, right ?

Comment: You wouldn't need to control conditional compilation within source code, right.

Comment: I was thinking to figure it out at the source code level, but after thought about your words, I think you have a better point. Separate the  implementation and compilation logic will make the structure cleaner. It's clean and straightforward. Thanks.